# ¿Como hago para que solo me salga el nombre de MARIA PAULA HERNANDEZ VIDAL en la columna (psa_nombres) y que no me salga el resto

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, subconsultas

esta es mi consulta :

```
SELECT p.psa_id, p.psa_nombres, pr.psa_fidelizado, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM cso_referido r
         INNER JOIN cso_persona p ON r.rdo_referido = p.psa_id
         INNER JOIN cso_persona pr ON r.rdo_simpatizante = pr.psa_id
WHERE r.rdo_referido = 67 OR r.rdo_referido
    IN( SELECT r2.rdo_simpatizante FROM cso_referido r2  where r2.rdo_referido = 67)
GROUP BY pr.psa_fidelizado;
```

Este es el resultado que me da:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estaria muy agradecido cualquiera que me pueda ayudar, gracias!!!

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, No has dado una explicación exacta de tu situación o problema, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: si no sabemos la estructura de tus tablas y no tenemos un ejemplo mínimo, difícilmente podremos ayudarte o darte una buena respuesta.